# cannot convert const wchar_t* to const char*

Tags: c++11, data-conversion

ALL,

Can someone explain to me why this code:

```
std::wstring query1 = L"SELECT....";
res = mysql_query( m_db, m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( query1.c_str() ).c_str() );
```

gives me an error from the subject?

I do have `-DUNICODE` defined inside C++ options

I guess I just need a pair of fresh eyes.

Thank you.

It is on Gentoo Linux with gcc5.4.

Comment: We'd need to know the types of the variables involved. At a guess, `mysql_query` only accepts `char*`, but I don't know the API. You've avoided all the definitions and code needed for a [MCVE].

Comment: what's unclear about the error? Also, you only posted part of the error message. The rest of it will tell you exactly which expression is erroneous

Comment: @ShadowRanger, type added.

Comment: @M.M, it's a second parameter to mysql_query() that fails.

Comment: Probably this `from_bytes` function returns `wstring`. If so, you will need to convert `wstring` to `string` before applying `c_str()`

Comment: @M.M, what's weird is that this code compiles successfully for SQLite and Postgres. There is no errors. I don't understand this.

Comment: I would guess that SQLite and Postgres do not call `mysql_query`

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to convert a unicode wide-character string to a const char*

```
char query_cstr[100];
size_t charsConverted;

wchar_t* unicode_query = L"SELECT * FROM table;";

wcstombs_s(&charsConverted, query_cstr, unicode_query, wcslen(unicode_query));

const char* query_const = query_cstr;

//Use query_const inside of mysql_query now that it's been converted to a const char*
```

I've run into trouble using the locale functions for various reasons. wcstombs_s() makes things a bit easier when converting unicode. Using c_str() on a std::wstring object will yield a const wchar_t* string, which is not what you want.

Comment: `wcstombs_s` takes 5 arguments but you only supplied 4. Also this function is optional in Standard C++, some compilers may not support it.

Comment: @M.M An overloaded version of wcstombs_s is as follows: `template <size_t size>
errno_t wcstombs_s(
   size_t *pReturnValue,
   char (&mbstr)[size],
   const wchar_t *wcstr,
   size_t count 
);` which compiles and runs successfully on Visual Studio. I'm not sure about other compilers, but I appreciate you pointing it out; good to know.